# How to get rid of this text style between divs

Tags: html

I have PHP page which generates these `div`s but when I use inspect element in Google Chrome between `div`s I see `" "` (as shown in the image).
How do I get rid of them?
[image: pic]

```
session_start();
 ob_start();
    $valid_user_id = trim($_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"]);
   if(isset($_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"]) && !empty($valid_user_id)) {
  include 'twitterconnection.php';
    $statuses = $connection->get('statuses/home_timeline', array('count' => '50',      'exclude_replies' => true));
    $ids = array();
 foreach ($statuses as $item) {
    $ids[] = $item->id;
    if (preg_match('~\p{Arabic}~u', $item->text) == true) {
        if ($item->retweeted_status) {
            include 're_pic_save.php';
                if (preg_match('~\p{Arabic}~u', $item->user->name) == true) {
                    $dir = '<span><a href="/'.$item->user->screen_name.'" ><b>'.$item->user->name.' </b></a>Retweeted by<img src="http://khavan.tk/yashar/img/retweet.PNG" /></span></div></div>';
                } else {
                    $dir = '<span>Retweeted by <a  href="/'.$item->user->screen_name.'" ><b>'.$item->user->name.'</b></a><img src="http://khavan.tk/yashar/img/retweet.PNG" /></span></div></div>';
                }
                include 'retweet_handle_fa.php';
                echo '<div class="row" style="direction: rtl; text-align: right;">';
                echo '<div style="float: left; padding-left: 47px; font-size: 10px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 5px;">';
                echo '<div>';
                echo $dir;
                echo '<div id="'.$item->retweeted_status->user->screen_name.'" class="mod-tg" style="padding-top: 17px;" data-modal="#notif-mod" onclick="send(this.id);"><input type="hidden" value="'.$item->retweeted_status->user->screen_name.'" />';
                echo '<div id="avatarr"><img style="cursor: pointer;" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/twitter/image/upload/v1393926049/avatars/'.$link.'" ></div><h2 style="cursor: pointer;display:inline;font-family: BKoodakBold,roboto;">'.$item->retweeted_status->user->name.'</h2><strong style="font-size:12px; float:left;cursor: pointer;color:#999;padding-top: 2px; padding-left: 3px;">'.$item->retweeted_status->user->screen_name.'<s>@</s></strong></div>';
                require_once 'timed.php';
                echo '<h6 style="color: #A88B2D;position: absolute; top: 35px;direction: ltr;">'.timePassed($item->retweeted_status->created_at).'</h6>';
                echo '<h4 class="farsi" style="padding-left: 20%;padding-top: 30px;line-height: 1.3;">'.$media0.'</h4>';
                echo '<div id="'.$item->id.'" onclick="show_tweet(this.id);" class="mod-tg" data-modal="#notif-mod" style="cursor: pointer;padding-left:48%;padding-top:2%;">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" value=" '.$item->id.'" />';
                echo '<span class="icon icon-circledown"></span></div></div>';
```

Comment: Can we see the PHP code that generates this HTML?

Comment: Edit your original post and put the PHP there.

Comment: Are you sure there are no empty variables passed? Because I think thats the issue.

Comment: Looks like its whatever you have in this file `include 'retweet_handle_fa.php';`

Comment: @wf4 no proble with that file lt's ok

Comment: if you remove that line of code, do you still get the same problem? In your picture, you get the `" "` just before you see `<div class="row"....` and this is where that file is included.

Comment: @wf4 is there any way to remove text from html? I mean any text aren't located in an element?

Comment: Yes, you can either do it server side which would be best, i.e. prevent it being created in the first place or using javascript by removing it once the dom has been created. This will point you in the right direction: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType